# Why this code does not work on Chrome?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i just installed mobiscroll. I use date scroller. I use this below code to manage the textbox.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        // create a datepicker with default settings
        $("#beginDate")
            .mobiscroll()
            .date({
                invalid: {
                    daysOfWeek: [0, 6],
                    daysOfMonth: ['5/1', '12/24', '12/25'],
                    theme: 'android-ics light',
                    display: 'bottom',
                    mode: 'scroller'
                }
            });
    });
</script>
```

It works well on firefox but not work on Chrome. Why? How can i fix it?

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: Take the last comma (after mode: 'scroller') out.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what "work" means? Also it's possible that the element doesn't exist at the time the function runs so try $(window).load() { }

Comment: the date screen does not appear when i click the textbox

Comment: @Lowkase: That should only cause problems in IE, not in Chrome

Comment: If your only debug mechanism is to use the "visual test", it will be very difficult to answer this question. What the rest of us are asking is, can you provide any further information like an actual debug or console error message?

Comment: i dont get any error in console .s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an extra comma here that my be a syntax error.

```
 , mode: 'scroller', }
```

Comment: The trailing comma will definitely cause problems in older versions of IE, but Chrome and others handle them without error.

Answer (score 0):

remove comma from

```
mode: 'scroller', });
    });
```